# Add EditText to Recycler

Tags: android-studio, android-recyclerview

I am new to android RecyclerView and it gives Error while i tried to add the Edittext fields to Recycler.I cannot find how to do this. Anyone please solve this issue and thanks in advance :) :) This is my mainactivity Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private CustomRecyclerAdapter mAdapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

private EditText mText;
private EditText mColor;

private List<Data> mData = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Initializing views.
    mText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textEt);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler);

    // If the size of views will not change as the data changes.
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    // Setting the LayoutManager.
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    // Setting the adapter.
    mAdapter = new CustomRecyclerAdapter();
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}

// Called when add button is clicked.
public void addItem(View view) {

    // Add data locally to the list.
    Data dataToAdd = new Data(
            mText.getText().toString());
    mData.add(dataToAdd);;

    // Update adapter.
    mAdapter.addItem(mData.size() - 1, dataToAdd);
}
```

}

The CustomRecyclerAdapter is

```
package com.example.niroj.jsonandsqlite;
public  class CustomRecyclerAdapter extends     
RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewHolder> {

private List<Data> mData = Collections.emptyList();

public CustomRecyclerAdapter() {
    // Pass context or other static stuff that will be needed.
}

public void updateList(List<Data> data) {
    mData = data;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mData.size();
}

@Override
public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int position) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext());
    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, viewGroup, false);
    return new RecyclerViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    viewHolder.title.setText(mData.get(position).text);

}


public void addItem(int position, Data data) {
    mData.add(position, data);
    notifyItemInserted(position);
}

public void removeItem(int position) {
    mData.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
}
```

}

The Data class have simply the contains

```
public class Data {
public String text;

public Data(String text) {
    this.text = text;

}

public String getText() {
    return text;
}

public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this ? Here is my code :-

This is MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements RecyclerViewAdapter.OnItemClickListener{

private RecyclerView myRecyclerView;

private LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;

private RecyclerViewAdapter myRecyclerViewAdapter;



EditText nameField;

Button btnAdd;



@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.myrecyclerview);



    linearLayoutManager =

            new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);

    /*

    linearLayoutManager =

            new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);

    */



    myRecyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this);

    myRecyclerViewAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    myRecyclerView.setAdapter(myRecyclerViewAdapter);

    myRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);



    nameField = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.namefield);

    btnAdd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.addbutton);

    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {

            String newName = nameField.getText().toString();



            if(!newName.equals("")){

                if(myRecyclerViewAdapter.getItemCount()>1){

                    myRecyclerViewAdapter.add(1, newName);

                }else{

                    myRecyclerViewAdapter.add(0, newName);

                }

            }

        }

    });

}



@Override

public void onItemClick(RecyclerViewAdapter.ItemHolder item, int position) {

    Toast.makeText(this,

            "Remove " + position + " : " + item.getItemName(),

            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    myRecyclerViewAdapter.remove(position);

 }
}
```

This is RecyclerViewAdapter.java

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends    
RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ItemHolder> {



private List<String> itemsName;

private OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;

private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;



public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context){

    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    itemsName = new ArrayList<String>();

}



@Override

public RecyclerViewAdapter.ItemHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View itemView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);

    return new ItemHolder(itemView, this);

}



@Override

public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewAdapter.ItemHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.setItemName(itemsName.get(position));

}



@Override

public int getItemCount() {

    return itemsName.size();

}



public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener){

    onItemClickListener = listener;

}



public OnItemClickListener getOnItemClickListener(){

    return onItemClickListener;

}



public interface OnItemClickListener{

    public void onItemClick(ItemHolder item, int position);

}



public void add(int location, String iName){

    itemsName.add(location, iName);

    notifyItemInserted(location);

}



public void remove(int location){

    if(location >= itemsName.size())

        return;



    itemsName.remove(location);

    notifyItemRemoved(location);

}



public static class ItemHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{



    private RecyclerViewAdapter parent;

    TextView textItemName;



    public ItemHolder(View itemView, RecyclerViewAdapter parent) {

        super(itemView);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

        this.parent = parent;

        textItemName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);

    }



    public void setItemName(CharSequence name){

        textItemName.setText(name);

    }



    public CharSequence getItemName(){

        return textItemName.getText();

    }



    @Override

    public void onClick(View v) {

        final OnItemClickListener listener = parent.getOnItemClickListener();

        if(listener != null){

            listener.onItemClick(this, getPosition());

        }

    }

}

}
```